# Do I need Redis if I have Cloudflare?

Tags: redis, cloudflare

My site is mainly image-based. I want to serve the content from cache to speed up the load speed and save bandwidth. I use mongoDB and parse server as backend and nextjs deployed on vercel as frontend. I'm planning to sign up for Cloudflare but I'm not sure if I should also get Redis? Are they different and should I go for both?

Answer (score 1):

Redis is used as a data cache, not the type of cache that is distributed images those are called CDNs which Cloudflare offers as a service.

Here is a post about Redis that I wrote that might help your understanding around Redis.

https://architecturenotes.co/redis/